# Android back button behavior after opening facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

In this example, after facebook app is opened, is there any way to get back to my activity in my app by using back button?

```
PackageInfo info =   context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
if(info.applicationInfo.enabled)
  return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("fb://profile/620681997952698"));
else
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/620681997952698"));
```

Comment: When you open facebook app from your app through an intent facebook will create its own backstack. Check this out for reference https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: so is there any way to override that behavior to use the back button to come back to my app?

Comment: Does it not go back to your app now? What version of the Facebook app do you have?

Comment: No I am using the latest version. It goes back to the facebook main news feed

Comment: That's not possible. When you are in facebook app, it will enter its own backstack. Only when its backstack is empty backbutton can back to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Please add Flag to Intent.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
```

You can see this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html)

Comment: You should not make an answer only around a link, the link can break or change... Always add a little text explaining what the link will explain, even if you put less details